# setup a vpn to connect between a google compute engine and app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, vpn

I want to transfer some of my applications to app engine from compute engine .

They still have to communicate as usaual .

Can I setup a vpn to enable that with as little to none code changes ?

Comment: You can use app-engine flexible environment and put your VM in the same network as your existing instances (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings)), or put them in new network and use cloud VPN (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview)) to connect the 2 networks.

Comment: hi @AvinoamMeir, thanks. I understand that using a flexible enviroment requires simple adding `vm: true` to the `worker.yaml` file . now how do I define a network in the yaml or anywhere else?

Comment: If you are using compute engine, you already have a network for your VMs. You can see it in cloud console. Of course you can create a new network in the same place.

Comment: Thanks, @AvinoamMeir , it worked. put it as an answer and i'll approve.

Comment: WebQube@ I did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use app-engine flexible environment and put your VM in the same network as your existing instances (see here), or put them in new network and use cloud VPN (see here) to connect the 2 networks.

example code :

```
network:
  name: shared-network
```